# Visual Studio Web essentials plugin and Microsoft.Web.Languages issue

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I have Web Essentials plugin installed on my Visual Studio 2012. Web Essentials version is 2.1. When I try to use the "Sort all properties" feature on a LESS file an alert message pops up:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Languages, Version=1.1.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24771839d8d21066' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I cannot use that feature of course. How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in version 2.2 that came out a week after 2.1